# Unable to generate Report when using jasmine-reporters in protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

i Used the following code in config

```
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');    
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.params.envi='DEVINT';
    //For output reports
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('./test', true, true));

},
```

When i ran the tests it ran successfully, but im not seeing any reports generated.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it would help but here is what is working for me:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    require("jasmine-reporters");

    // junit reporter
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
        var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
        var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
        var prePendStr = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new
            jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter("test-results", true, true, prePendStr));
    });
},
```

Using `jasmine` 1.3, `jasmine-reporters` 1.0.1, `protractor` 2.0.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. It was sloved by:

```
framework: "jasmine2",  //must set it if you use JUnitXmlReporter

    onPrepare: function(){  //configure junit xml report

        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            filePrefix: 'guitest-xmloutput',
            savePath: 'test/reports'
        }));

    },
```

Look on the current documentation of https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters. At the bottom is the instruction for protractor. I solved the same problem by adding this to protractor.conf.js

Answer (score 0):

[s-patchamatla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4525297/s-patchamatla)
You need to downgrade version of Jasmine to jasmine-reporters@1.0.0

Newer versions of jasmine reporters does no longer attaches to the Jasmine object

so, in case you tried to use jasmine-reporters with Protractor, you need to use a 1.x version of jasmine-reporters.

npm install jasmine-reporters@~1.0.0

```
onPrepare: function () {
    require("jasmine-reporters");

    // junit reporter
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
        var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
        var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
        var prePendStr = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new
            jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(<report path>, true, true, prePendStr));
    });
}
```

i guess this should work for you.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks