# Protractor test reports

Tags: jasmine, output, protractor

I've established a considerable set of protractor test suites and I'm looking to implement it into jenkins to run these tests with each new build. To handle the output, simply outputting it to a text file doesn't suffice anymore e.g. `protractor conf.js --suite [suiteName] > output.text`

I've found protractor reporters [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter)  and [here](https://github.com/swissmanu/protractor-screenshot-reporter) but I haven't found any information on manually manipulating the protractor output to represent it more clearly and attractively without the use of external frameworks / libraries.

Appreciate any input!

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652810/unable-to-generate-report-when-using-jasmine-reporters-in-protractor

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the reply, I've looked at the jasmine-reporters plugin but I'm looking to manipulate the output myself rather than using a predefined plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a custom Jasmine reporter. The reporter API is explained in the [Jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/custom_reporter.html).

Since you only want to do stuff with test results, you only need to implement the `specDone` callback. Your reporter would look something like this:

```
var myReporter = {
  specDone: function(results)( {
    writeToFile('Suite started: ' + result.description + ' whose full description is: ' + result.fullName);
  }
};
```

Then you can add your reporter to Jasmine in your conf file:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(myReporter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my project could satisfy your requirements partially and I would like to give you more input with executable solution.

You can generate readability test report automatically with this project. You have to install an additional module with NPM and add a few line in your protractor config file.

http://vorachet.github.io/protractor-build-verification-testreport/

Excerpt:

> protractor-build-verification-testreport
>
> Build verification test (Smoke testing ,Confidence testing, Sanity
>   testing) is done by testers before accepting a new build. Build
>   verification test is also one of the most cost-effective method for
>   identifying and fixing defects in software.
>
> protractor-build-verification-testreport provides a Node.js module
>   used to generate readability HTML test report based on Protractor
>   environment. If Protractor is an equipment in your build verification
>   test process, protractor-build-verification-testreport could help you
>   doing test report tasks effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Email-able Report

```
import:  var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
```

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: './emailable-report/',
            consolidateAll: false,
            screenshotsFolder: 'reportsscreenshots',
            takeScreenshots: true,
            takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true
        }));
```

Summary Report

```
import:  var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');
```

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: './summary-report',
            screenshotsSubfolder: 'images',
            jsonsSubfolder: 'jsons',
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            docTitle: 'NAVA 2.1 Tablet Site Automation Execution Summary ..'
        }).getJasmine2Reporter());
```

- protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter
- protractor-beautiful-reporterist item

Answer (score 0):

**Install protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter via NPM**

```
npm install protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter --save-dev
```

In your Protractor configuration file, register protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter in jasmine:

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
```

> // Setup the report before any tests start
>
> ```
> beforeLaunch: function() {
>     return new Promise(function(resolve) {
>         reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
>     })
> },
>
>
> onPrepare: function() {
>     browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
>     jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
>         new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
>             savePath: 'target/screenshots', // put your destination file
>         })
>     );
>
>
>
>     jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
>         displayFailuresSummary: true,
>         displayFailedSpec: true,
>         displaySuiteNumber: true,
>         displaySpecDuration: true
>     }));
>
>     jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
> },
> ```
>
> // Close the report after all tests finish
>
> ```
> afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
>     return new Promise(function(resolve) {
>         reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
>     });
> },
> ```